# When get QRcode in flex 4.6 the camera frames become too slow

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, camera, android-camera, qr-code

I'm using flex 4.6 to build mobile application , i want to get the qr-code dynamically when the camera detect it so i use zing library to get it and it works well when press to button , but i want to make it without button that the camera open and check for it the i build a timer to repeat every 1 millisecond but the frames of the camera become too slow how can i increase the performance of it to became as the speed of the camera in normal .

code snippets :

```
            protected function tryAgain(event:TimerEvent):void
        {           
            videoDisplay.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED,button1_clickHandler);
            System.gc();
            decodeSnapshot();
        }
        protected function onTimerComplete():void
        {
            lbl.text="finished";
        }
        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (!cameraStarted) {
                if (Camera.isSupported)
                {
                    camera=Camera.getCamera();
                    camera.setMode(360, 360, 24);

                    videoDisplay.x = 360;
                    sv.addChild(videoDisplay);

                    videoDisplay.attachCamera(camera);
                    videoDisplay.rotation=90;
                    qrReader=new QRCodeReader;
                    lbl.text = "";
                    cameraStarted = true;
                    decodeSnapshot();
                }
                else {
                    lbl.text = "No Camera ";
                    }
            }
            else {
                decodeSnapshot();
            }
        }

        public function decodeSnapshot():void
        {
            myTimer.stop();
            lbl.text="Check in progress";
            bmd=new BitmapData(300, 300);
            bmd.draw(videoDisplay, null, null, null, null, true);
            videoDisplay.cacheAsBitmap=true;
            videoDisplay.cacheAsBitmapMatrix=new Matrix;
            decodeBitmapData(bmd, 300, 300);
            bmd.dispose();
            bmd=null;
            System.gc();
        }
        public function getAllHints():HashTable
        {
            var ht:HashTable=new HashTable;
            ht.Add(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
            return ht;
        }

        public var tempObj:Object = new Object();
        protected var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1,0);
        protected var saveManager:PersistenceManager = new PersistenceManager();

        public var userName:String;
        public var pass:String;
        public var qr:String;

        private var _data:Object;

        public function decodeBitmapData(bmpd:BitmapData, width:int, height:int):void
        {
            var lsource:BufferedImageLuminanceSource=new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(bmpd);
            var bitmap:BinaryBitmap=new BinaryBitmap(new GlobalHistogramBinarizer(lsource));

            var ht:HashTable=null;
            ht=this.getAllHints();

            var res:Result=null;
            try {
                res=qrReader.decode(bitmap, ht);
            }
            catch (event:Error) {
            }
            if (res == null) {
                videoDisplay.clear();


                    myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER , tryAgain);
                    myTimer.start();


            }

            else {

                myTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER , tryAgain);               
                camera.removeEventListener(ActivityEvent.ACTIVITY,button1_clickHandler);
                var parsedResult:ParsedResult=ResultParser.parseResult(res);


                lbl.text=parsedResult.getDisplayResult();

                var saveManager:PersistenceManager = new PersistenceManager();
                saveManager.setProperty("QRstring", parsedResult.getDisplayResult());



                videoDisplay.clear();
                sv.removeChild(videoDisplay);

                cameraStarted = false;
                btn.visible=false;

                qRcode(userName , pass,qr, lbl.text);


            }
        }
```

Update :Can any one help me to how to handle the camera when move to work without stop the frames when moves
i try to open the camera in the user and the scanner worked in behind it that when scan the camera continue worked , but i cannot do it.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0):

I am using zing library. I had camera performance issues when I was using a hint type called "TRY_HARDER"

the code that adds the hints looks like this:

```
var ht:HashTable=new HashTable;
ht.Add(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS,BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
ht.Add(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER,true);
var res:Result = myReader.decode(bitmap, ht);
```

Comment: Additional details as to exactly what kind of issues that you are facing would help others to provide better answers.